# Use C# Console.WriteLine in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

If I call `Console.WriteLine` in a Windows Service, are the logs written anywhere in a sort of "hidden" console?

I'm NOT interested in finding out where Windows Service writes `Console.WriteLine`'s logs, I'm just wondering if the service still writes the log in a background console (invisible to the user) when `Console.WriteLine` is called.

Comment: No. the service has no console attached, so the output is just going into the void.

Comment: Then why I've got an error in Console.WriteLine

Comment: Please show relevant code, are you using any special parameters? Is it calling `ToString` on something which is failing?

Comment: "Then why I've got an error in Console.WriteLine" - why not ask about *this*?

Answer (score 2):

Services have no allocated consoles, stdout data will silently get dropped.

Unless of course at any point you attach something to it, like a debugger that hooks into stdout, in which case you'll start seeing your messages.

Comment: I'm asking so because the windows service I'm developping reported the following error after months it was working regularly:

" Exception Info: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
   at System.Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(System.Array, Int32, System.Array, Int32, Int32)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[], Int32, Int32)
   at System.IO.TextWriter+SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(System.String)
   at System.Console.WriteLine(System.String) " ....... if windows service skips Console.WriteLine, I'm wondering why I have this error.

Comment: Isn't no error good?

Comment: Exception Info: System.IndexOutOfRangeException at System.Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(System.Array, Int32, System.Array, Int32, Int32) at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[], Int32, Int32) at System.IO.TextWriter+SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(System.String) at System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)

Comment: Nobody says it skips anything, I just said the output gets silently dropped. All of the code to build the parameters of the function, including the function itself, still run synchronously.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you! Any idea why Console.WriteLine could have returned this error? Because the only thing that comes in my mind is that after months of logging somewhere, a console buffer anywhere got full.

Comment: No, I don't think that's the case. It's obviously trying to copy your string byte data to an internal `TextWriter` buffer, it has nothing to do with anything else. My first thought here is either memory corruption (if you do any P/Invoke or C++ or pointer stuff) or some kind of malformed string. Check the value you're trying to print at crash time.